# How do i query MySQL table with a where clause involving three conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple columns. I want to count the number of posts by a member that meets three conditions.

From Includes folder:

```
function active_posts_number($data){
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE (post_block = 0 AND user_id = ' . $data . ') AND post_activation = 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $number_of_posts = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1){
        $number_of_posts = 0;
    }
    //$number_of_posts = mysql_num_rows($result);
    return $number_of_posts;
}
```

Page:

```
 $active_posts = active_posts_number($_SESSION["user_id"]);
```

Response:
check mysql server version to use near ' WHERE (post_block = 0'

I've changed the function in many ways but still not getting expected result (3). 
I know that's not an appropriate way to COUNT, but that's what I can come up with to get what I want.

'Will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: if all AND, than no need to use brackets `SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE post_block = 0 AND user_id = ' . $data . ' AND post_activation = 1`

Comment: maybe your SESSION is not working..

Comment: Looks strange, I do not recall `post` being a reserved word, but give it a try anyway to enclose it in backticks. Also make sure that the white space before `WHERE` really is a blank and not some other unprintable character. So retype that part of the query, save it and try again.

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION);` check this where u are calling your function.

Comment: @devpro That would not explain the error the OP gets, would it?

Comment: `user_id = ' . $data . '` maybe `$data` is empty..

Comment: @devpro Sure, got that, but that would lead to another error or better simply no records getting returned.

Comment: without OP response, cant explain :)

Comment: For that(if data is empty and you want to get no records) use this query "SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE (post_block = 0 AND user_id = '" . $data . "') AND post_activation = 1";

Comment: @arkascha: do u think `user_id` is a string id???

Comment: @devpro No, why that? Don't get me wrong, enclosing that `$data` in single quotes certainly does make sense. All I say is that the OP would get another error message of that were the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in using brackets. You can use them or not.In your query problem is of single quotes. It breaking your query. Use double quotes if you started your query with single quotes.

```
$query = 'SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE (post_block = 0 AND user_id = " . $data . ") AND post_activation = 1';
```

it will cause no error. Always echo your query and run on phpmyadmin if you face this type error.

Comment: Sorry, but this would result in `$data` _not_ getting replaced, since you use it in a string delimited with single quotes. You want to try that yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I think you need quotes around data:
Right now your query would probably look like

```
SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE (post_block = 0 AND user_id = scott) AND post_activation = 1
```

Comment: This is correct, _but_ it would result in a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, its working for me. But also you should check your db connect and the session.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "12345689";
$hostname = "localhost";
$db_name = 'test_db';

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); //mysql connection
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$dbhandle) or die("Could not select test_db"); //selecting db

function active_posts_number($data){
    global $dbhandle; //mysql connection
    $query = "SELECT count(post_id) AS number_of_posts FROM post WHERE (post_block = 0 AND user_id = '$data') AND post_activation = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle);
    $str = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $number_of_posts = $str->number_of_posts;
    return $number_of_posts;
}

// you should check the user_id of session.
$user_id        = 20; //$_SESSION["user_id"];
$active_posts   = active_posts_number($user_id);

print_r($active_posts);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this if you count total number of post_id based on your condition

```
SELECT count(post_id) as cnt FROM post WHERE post_block = 0 AND user_id = ' . $data . ' AND post_activation = 1;
```

and result will be

```
total = $row1->cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = 'SELECT post_id FROM `post` WHERE post_block = 0 AND user_id = '$data' AND post_activation = 1';
```

Comment: This also will result in the literal string `$data` contained in the query, which does not make sense.